# How to prevent the Appium from changing the name of the apk file when copied to the device

Tags: apk, appium, appium-android

I have been doing some malicious APK threat detection by our security threat detection app I have been doing some malicious APK threat detection using zIPS test automation.

I was able to **copy** file(**sideloaded_malicious_file.apk**) from laptop on to an Android(iOS later stage) device under folder **“/sdcard”** using **pushFile** Appium command.

First I could not physically verify the copied malicious apk file in the file structure of the device. After installing few third party file managers, I could able to locate a file called **appiump.tmp** with the exact file size and the time of transfer under the 'internal storage' folder.

When I check using programmatically to locate (**sideloaded_malicious_file.apk**) file, it is locatable.
This is causing our security threat detection app, fail to detect the malicious application presence in the device.

> Why Android or Appium (???) is changing the name from
> (sideloaded_malicious_file.apk) to appiump.tmp ??

It is required to be prevented, the reason being our security threat detection app need to identify it as it is like a malicious file, and detect it and list it in the threats,   and show a pop up that a malicious file is being found.

Comment: Or in the least, I could try renaming the file to the original name, after copying is done. Is there a way to rename a file using Appium ?

Comment: Please see the related question: How to rename a file ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637424/how-to-rename-a-file-in-appium-after-copying-it-in-to-the-device-using-pushfile