# How to rename a file in Appium after copying it in to the device using pushFile()?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

I am using **pushFile()** to copy a file in to the folder ***"/sdcard"***, which gets copied to **"/internal storage/"** folder inside the device, but with a different name and extension like **"Appium.tmp"**. For our threat detection app to work it has to be having a name like     **"<my_malicious_app.apk>"** file.

How do I rename the file after being copied from **"Appium.tmp"**
to **"<my_malicious_app.apk>"** ??

Comment: Is your Apium version above 1.15.0? Also Are you using the approach mentioned here to push your apk file? Are you saying that, apk file is getting renamed to tmp file?

Comment: If your answer is YES to all the questions above, i would ask you to try zipping the file and then push to the device using appium command and then use `adb shell unzip /sdcard/your_zip_file_name.zip` to unzip the file on device.

Comment: @HemChe
Yes, I am using 1.22.1 Appium. Yes, I am using pushFile() approach from the documentation. 
Sure, I will try doing the process advised by you, and post the result. It may take few days though, as I was doing some thing else right now. Thanks though.

Having one doubt, when I am running Appium Java code in a project, how do I run the "adb shell" command ? How does adb class is available ?

Comment: It's possible. Please follow this guide. https://appiumpro.com/editions/3-running-arbitrary-adb-commands-via-appium